# What is the purpose of the Id property in the BootstrapperApplicationRef element?

Tags: wix

In a Wix Bundle, what is the purpose of the `Id` property of a `BootstrapperApplicationRef` element? Where is it referenced, and why should I care what I put in there? It is required so I can I put garbage in it?

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bootstrapperapplicationref.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Id` element must be set to `ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost` if you want to use a custom WiX managed bootstrapper application.

Otherwise, if you are using the standard wix bootstrapper application, it must be set to one of the following options:

```
WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense
WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense
WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkSidebarLicense
WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLargeLicense
WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLargeLicense
WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.Foundation
```

For more info:

- http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/
- http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/